# How to open an HTML JavaScript page in a wx.Python or other python gui window?

Tags: python, html, editor

Is there any way to open a browser based editor (such as CKEdit, tinymce, or any other HTML + JavaScript editor) in a Python window (perhaps wx.Python) rather than in a browser?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you try using Webkit python bindings.
You can load an arbitrary Webview and put it anywhere as a GTK widget:

http://code.google.com/p/pywebkitgtk/

I'm not sure about WX.

One complexity you will find is how to get the values from JS into Python.

Here's an article describing a trick to call the sandboxed JS from Python:

http://www.aclevername.com/articles/python-webgui/

Good luck!